# How to solve codeigniter SMTP TLS email connection error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, starttls

I have smtp mail and i am sending verification mail of account at webproject.
Webprject is developed using codeigniter 3.0.

I tested with using gmail, it was working perfectly. 
Now i have to put smtp mail instead of gmail.
It does not seem to have successful connection to the smtp account.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.company.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'support@company.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_pass'] = '******'; //change this
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls'; 
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Received error like this

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`outlook.com' did not match expected CN=`mail.company.com'
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1978
```

Comment: check first your configured smtp mail details. we need to set only `host`, `username`, `password` and `port no`.

Comment: I don't understand. can you clarify more.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error you get refer to "mail.company.com", which is a bogus address, I suppose. I think it's the reason why you get this error. To use SMTP, you need a real SMTP account, not a bogus one. This is why there is the "change this" comments in your code. You should actually change those lines, and put the real credential.

Comment: You were right. Thank You.
The account in the config exist and all the configs are correct. 

The error happen during sending email script. 
I put in the no-reply@company.com in the sender. That email not exist. 
As soon as i change to same as config, It is working.

Answer (score 1):

set "$config['starttls'] = true" if you using smtp_crypto = tls

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is required otherwise mail sending fails:

```
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
```